# Open Document in Google Docs, unable to convert Document

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, python-docx

I used the following snippet to create .docx file using python-docx and uploaded to Google Drive, but Google is not able to convert it to google docs, is there anything I can do to make it convertible to google docs. FYI, I do not have Microsoft word available to open in Microsoft Word first.

```
def generate_docx(dir_name, srt_files):
  fpath = os.path.join(dir_name, "output.docx")
  document = Document()
  for index, srt_file in sorted(srt_files.items()):
      document.add_heading(f"{srt_file.index}. {srt_file.title}", level=1)
      for _sentences in srt_file.paragraphs():
          document.add_paragraph(" ".join(_sentences))
      document.add_page_break()
  document.save(fpath)
return fpath
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this document about [Importing to Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads). You can upload your `.docx` file to Google Drive with the `mimetype:application/vnd.google-apps.document` to import it as a Google Doc.

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'My Report',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/report.csv',
                        mimetype='text/csv',
                        resumable=True)
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```